# Android Path / Region < API 19

Tags: android, geometry, intersection

I'm trying to find the intersection of 2 (or more) paths or regions in Android.

This is easy when stipulating >= API level 19

```
// onDraw(Canvas oCanvas)....
Paint oPaint = new Paint();
oPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
oPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

Path oPath1 = new Path();
oPath1.addCircle(200, 400, 100, Direction.CW); // (X,Y,Radius,Direction)    
oCanvas.drawPath(oPath1, oPaint);

Path oPath2 = new Path();
oPath2.addCircle(400, 400, 150, Direction.CW); // (X,Y,Radius,Direction)
oCanvas.drawPath(oPath2, oPaint);
oPath1.op(oPath2, Op.INTERSECT);

// Draw intersection area in red.
oPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
oCanvas.drawPath(oPath1, oPaint);
```

I've noticed that Region has an op which is available at API level 1.

So, how do I achieve the above effect, but for all API levels?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Region.setPath`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html#setPath%28android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Region%29) to turn a `Path` (like in your question text) into a `Region`. Then you can use [`op`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Region.html#op%28android.graphics.Region,%20android.graphics.Region.Op%29) much like your API 19 code does.